# Get file content together with 400 Bad Request

Tags: json, server, configuration, frontend

I am running usual web server. Port 80. Everything is as usual. Under the server, there are some files. Config files, INI files, JSON files and so on. When I try with POSTMAN to get some JSON file:
[image]

I DO receive the content of file: ***single_stats.json***, but also I get resonce from server: ***400 Bad Request***

Do you know why it happens ? I mean why I receive an error ? And if there is an error, why I receive content of file ?